# Adding Funscript to an existing ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, f#, funscript

I really like the FunScript's idea of writing F# instead of Javascript, but I cannot find any samples on how to integrate FunScript int an existing ASP.NET MVC solution.

Is it even possible? A "real-world example" would be really useful.

Comment: FunScript is focused on F# to JavaScript compilation for Single Page Applications. For F# to JavaScript compilation and excellent ASP.Net MVC integration out-of-the-box it's worth considering [WebSharper](http://www.websharper.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Igor, you can check out the blog post that I have written and the solution that accompanies on it on Github.

http://namelessinteractive.com/FullStackFSharpLongVersion_Part1

Essentially it is an MVC application with FunScript integration.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the answers. I guess integrating FunScript to an existing C# project would be the same.

Comment: Very similar I believe. The main thing you need from F# is the FunScript.Compiler.Compiler.Compile <@ main() @> I think. If you need more details the follow up blog post will go into more details on FunScript and with it I will upload the final version of the solution to GitHub. If you need it sooner, I can send you the demo solution in its not cleaned up form.

Answer (score -5):

F# is for server not for the Client
so i think use f# is not a good idea
if you do not like  Javascript 
use TypeScript is a good idea

Comment: Funscript is a converter from F# to Javascript, to be used on the client.